# how to process the blank in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to put all the names of files in a dir to a variable. I wrote as below:

```
DATA=`ls`
for LOOP in $DATA
do
    echo $LOOP
done
```

But there're some file names include the blank. Then the file named "A B.txt" will be interpreted to two files "A" and "B.txt".

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't parse the output of `ls`, that almost always will get you in trouble.

Just use:

```
for loop in * ; do
 echo "$loop"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

While the advice not to parse `ls` output is a general wisdom the command can be coerced to output parseable data:

```
   `ls -b`
```

would replace nongraphic characters including spaces with C-style escapes.

Yet this would not work in with shell for loop, however can be used when the output is sent through a pipe to another command.

Example:

```
  $ ls -b
  A\ B.txt  C.txt
```

Fails in a for loop:

```
  $ for i in $(ls -b) ; do echo $i ; done
  A\
  B.txt
  C.txt
```

Yet works when sent through a pipe

```
  $ ls -b | xargs -n 1 echo 
  A B.txt
  C.txt
```